# How to write a SQL Query in a better way for optimization?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

When I execute the below query it took nearly 4 min.

This is the query

```
SELECT
    transactionsEntry.StoreID StoreID,
    items.ItemLookupCode ItemLookupCode,
    SUM(transactionsEntry.Quantity)
FROM
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] transactionsEntry
RIGHT JOIN 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] transactions ON transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber = transactions.TransactionNumber
INNER JOIN 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] items ON transactionsEntry.ItemID = items.ID
WHERE
    YEAR(transactions.Time) = 2015 
    AND MONTH(transactions.Time) = 1
GROUP BY
    transactionsEntry.StoreID, items.ItemLookupCode
ORDER BY 
    items.ItemLookupCode
```

`TransactionEntry` table may have 90 billion records, `Transaction` table has 30 billion records, `item` table has 40 k records.

Estimation Cost
[image: for this query]. It shows 84%. and it is clustered index.

Comment: General tip, never use RIGHT JOIN since it's too confusing for most people. Switch to LEFT JOIN instead, as it is much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: try filtering the records from transaction table initially and then join with the respective tables..

Comment: @ps_prakash02 you are right. Now it reduce one min. But still taking time 2 min 30 sec

Comment: Since you INNER JOIN transactionsEntry with Items, the RIGHT JOIN with transactions is meaningless and it actually interpreted and INNER JOIN. On top of that I doubt it if you have records in transactionsEntry without matching records in transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Index for all the table which and all you are using in your query.
That is the better way for to produce the result very fastly.

for example

> Create index for `Time and TransactionNumber in Transaction Table`
>
> Create index for `TransactionNumber, ItemID and StoreID in TransactionEntry Table`
>
> Create index for `ItemID in Item Table`.

Please visit this site. [You can learn from the basic for query tuning and SQL optimization](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-query-tuning.htm)

Comment: I'm confused. "mohamed faisal" is answering questions from "mohamed faisal" ? Is this some kind of reputation generating scheme ?

Comment: @deroby When I was in Egypt some years back, I met a guy named Mohamed. He told me: "His uncle's name is Mohamed; his cousin, Mohamed; his brother-in-law, Mohamed; his father's name was also Mohamed; but his mother's name - not Mohamed". (The joys of regionally iconic names.) That aside, both mohameds have asked questions using suspiciously similar tables. Although there may still be a more innocent explanation considering that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41342365/224704) mohamed didn't seem to understand mohamed's answer; but did manage to test it successfully.

Comment: This answer suggest indexes that could help but doesn't actually say anything about "how to write the query better", which is _what the question actually asked_. The irony that the first index is **unuseable** without "writing the query better" to make it SARGable.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid function calls - they prevent usage of indexes. Try

```
Where transactions.Time >= '2015-01-01'
  and transactions.Time <  '2015-02-01'
```

If you  don't have an index on the column `transactions.Time` then add an index for this column.

Comment: What do you mean `If you don't have one then add an index to transactions.Time.`?

Comment: Now better understandable?

Comment: Now it reduce 24 sec, it reduce the result from 3 min 44 sec to 3 min 20 sec

Comment: Look at the execution plan and check what is taking so long.

Comment: now you can see, I updated. That cost is taking 84 % and that column name is `autoID` as well as it is primary key

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the Clustered Index Scan.

I recommend creating a Covering Index on [transactionsentry]:

```
Key Columns:[TransactionNumber],[ItemID]

Include:[StoreID]
```

Also try this Index on [Transaction]:

```
Key Columns:[time],[TransactionNumber]
```

(Sorry I can't provide greater depth, but I don't know your current Indexing structure)

Answer (score -1):

Try This code once it may help you

```
select  transactionsEntry.StoreID StoreID,items.ItemLookupCode ItemLookupCode,SUM(transactionsEntry.Quantity)
FROM   [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] transactionsEntry
INNER JOIN [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] items ON transactionsEntry.ItemID = items.ID
RIGHT JOIN [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] transactions ON transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber = transactions.TransactionNumber
Where  transactions.[Time] >= '2015-01-01'   and transactions.[Time] < '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY transactionsEntry.StoreID,items.ItemLookupCode
ORDER BY items.ItemLookupCode
```

Comment: there is nothing difference from my query except the where clause. That is also suggested already. Better luck next time

Comment: @mohamedfaisal check the query again ..you better use the right join after the inner join.